# rpart execution in R Studio

Tags: r, analytics, prediction, rpart

I am working on Titanic dataset. I am trying to fill in blanks in CABIN column. I have extracted first letter from CABIN column values, then put those in CABIN_NEW column. After that I use `rpart` for prediction, but somehow every time I run the code below, R takes a lot of time (haven't finished one time yet, every time, I have to terminate it).

DATAset has 1309 rows and the columns I am using are below in code. The system I am using is running on 4 GB Ram, i5 processor and Window 7.

```
combifit  <- rpart(Cabin_New ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp + Parch + Fare + Embarked + Title
                     + FamilySize + Surname + FamilyID,
                    data = combi[!is.na(combi$Cabin_New),], method = 'class')
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have used a lot of factor variables. Please check how many factor levels are present in each of the factor. If that is high, lets say for Surname, if it is 100, then R will have to create 100 variables and so on for all the other factors. So my guess is that because of these factor variables, rpart has to look into a lot of variables, to decide on split. Hence will take a lot of time.

Also read up a bit on `rpart.control`, as number of splits that rpart does depends on the parameters that are passed to the `rpart`.For example `cp` is one such parameter. Its default value is 0.01. Try changing its value to from 0.5 to 0.1. Play around similarly with other parameters, and you might be able to run `rpart` faster.